# Is there a neat way to tell if iPhone/iPad has been set a passcode by user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad-2

I have asked this question long before.

I know it maybe impossible, but as far as I know, 'Find my friends' has this features and it works just so well, so I wonder if now there is a neat and legitimate way of doing that.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: well, for security purposes, the application I am working on has some important information and every time it starts up, it check if the device is passcode protected and if not, warning the user

Answer (score 1):

Just because Apple's Find My Friends app has a feature does not mean the API is publicly available. If this app is not an enterprise app, you can't use private APIs and have your app put on the app store. If it is an enterprise app, you may want to look into setting up a configuration profile for the device. In order to access the VPN for my employer, I had to install a configuration profile (visible in Settings) that requires a passcode to be entered every time I unlock my iPad. Without that, I cannot VPN into their intranet. TestFlight uses a similar approach with profiles to register a device to receive builds. I would check out this link from Apple on setting up these sorts of profiles for enterprise applications: http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/resources/

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to detect this programmatically from within an iPhone SDK-based application. If you need to, you should file an enhancement request with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: but the 'find my friends' app by apple(with iOS 5) does have such a great feature, I don't think the answer is simply 'no way' but 'no a publicly known way'

Comment: Yes but find my friends is an application created by apple. So I guess there is a way but it is probably an api that would cause your app to be rejected from the itunes app store, because that is accessing protected information about the iPhone user.